# communication and sharing data between components in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have two component in my angular 4 application and i want to share values between them.

the first component has a dropdown button which ,when selecting an item,allows me to send data to another component to print it.

i wrote this code
 the service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private message : String ;

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.message=message;
    }

    getMessage(): String {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

the component wich has the dropdown button

```
export class ToolbarDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  message: any ;


  constructor(private loginservice:LoginService,private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  sendMessage(): void {
this.dataService.sendMessage(this.message);
}

}
```

the other component

```
 constructor(
           private dataservice: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {    


console.log("emitted message is"+this.dataservice.getMessage());



  }
```

Comment: are they parent child or siblings

Comment: That's what [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) are for.

Comment: @wassim There are plenty of similar questions

Comment: Like @msanford suggested, services are your way to go. Register your service in your `app.module` and inject it in both components. Then the service is shared between them.

Comment: I edited my post and i added the used code

Answer (score 0):

If your components have no connection to each other (child parent etc.) I would recommend using service for that. However, I assume your components are related and in that case you can use Inputs and Outputs to do that.

If your components are both children of the same parent you can output the value to the parent and then input to the second child.

Answer (score -1):

you can use an attribute of the first component as input for the seconde component so you can watch it in the second component and update your interface.

I hope this helped you.